# how to manipulate column header strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

how to remove part of string "test_" in column headers. image the dataframe has many columns, so df.rename(columns={"test_Stock B":"Stock B"}) is not the solution i am looking for!

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Stock A':[1, 1, 1, 1],
           'test_Stock B':[3, 3, 4, 4],
           'Stock C':[4, 4, 3, 2],
           'test_Stock D':[2, 2, 2, 3],
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# expect
data = {'Stock A':[1, 1, 1, 1],
           'Stock B':[3, 3, 4, 4],
           'Stock C':[4, 4, 3, 2],
           'Stock D':[2, 2, 2, 3],
           }

df_expacte = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I expect all column headers only labeled as "Stock x" instead of "test_Stock x". Thank you for the ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the columns via list comprehension with:

```
df.columns = [x.replace("test_","") for x in df]
```

This outputs:

```
   Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
0        1        3        4        2
1        1        3        4        2
2        1        4        3        2
3        1        4        2        3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean your data before converting it to the dataframe using this code:

```
cleaned_data = {k.replace('test_', ''): v for k,v in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If need extract values `Stock x` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
#if need uppercase letter after Stock + space
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(Stock\s+[A-Z]{1})', expand=False)
#if need any value after Stock + space
#df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(Stock\s+.*)', expand=False)
print (df)
   Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
0        1        3        4        2
1        1        3        4        2
2        1        4        3        2
3        1        4        2        3
```

Or if need remove `test_` use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('test_', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Stock A':[1, 1, 1, 1],
           'test_Stock B':[3, 3, 4, 4],
           'Stock C':[4, 4, 3, 2],
           'test_Stock D':[2, 2, 2, 3],
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.columns = [x.replace('test_','') for x in df.columns]
```

output :

```
print(df)
Out[9]: 
   Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
0        1        3        4        2
1        1        3        4        2
2        1        4        3        2
3        1        4        2        3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression (see [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) to replace or remove the prefix "test_". The column headers can be treated either as a python list or as a pandas series. In any case you can apply iteratively the substitution on each element of the column headers.

Option A

Pandas has a collection of [string processing methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) which you can access via the `str` attribute of pandas Series. As column headers is a Series, you can replace the desired pattern with,

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'^test_', '')
```

Option B

The regex module can be used to replace the desired pattern using the `re.sub` method on each column header, using a list comprehension.

```py
import re
df.columns = [re.sub(r'^test_', '', col) for col in df.columns]
```